# "Device invalid" error trying to open Google Drive remote files with LibreOffice

Tags: libreoffice, authentication, remote, google-drive

---

**Premise:** I have never used LibreOffice's remote access option before - I just discovered it today and I think it might be very useful for me: I don't know how (nor whether) it works.

---

I'd like to access my files on Google Drive with LibreOffice. I have never done that before, so I must add my account to LibreOffice.

I'm trying to do that with `File > Open remote... > Manage services > Add service`. I fill the form with my username and password and hit `OK`:

[image: "File Services" form]

Now LibreOffice asks for a "6 digit PIN" (good, I use 2FA, looks like it successfully connected to Google's server):

[image: "Authentication Code" form]

But when I enter my PIN and hit `OK` again I get an error saying that "The specified device is invalid":

[image: "device invalid" error]

I supposed it was related to the login process, so I tried to combine

1. my username with and without the "@gmail.com" suffix, and
2. the "normal" and an "app-specific" password I created *ad hoc* (https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en)

but LibreOffice keeps resulting in the error. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem with LibreOffice has not been fixed and it used to work a long time ago
There was a plugin made for this but it also does not work any longer.

The solution is to install [google drive](https://www.google.com/drive/download/) separately on your PC and sync the files to filesystem. Then you can open the files in LO and "Kind of" use it the same way you intend to.

However LO does not open gdrive native format.
to fix this

1. Export for example your *.gsheet  as xlsx
2. copy over this xlsx to the syncd google drive in your pc
3. Now you can open this xlsx both in online google drive and LO